# Send e-mail without persist anything in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app, I want that my client can send a few informations by e-mail directly from the page. So until now a created a controller, view and the specific route.

Every tutorial that I was able to find people put the action mailer on the create method or update. In this case I only put a few inputs on the page and submit button. 
It's possible to do this?


Controller name: contato_controller

The view: contato/index.html.erb

I also set the configurations on the Production.rb basing on the another question I find:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     address: "smtp.gmail.com",
     port: 587,
     domain: 'localhost',
     user_name: 'username',
     password: 'password',
     authentication: 'plain',
     enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActionMailer does not require, nor does it use a database. It just needs a Notifier class to trigger emails. This is covered in the [ActionMailer guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

Remember that `create` and `update` methods in your controller are also not linked to any sort of database unless you're involving models in your code. It is only by convention that `create` actually creates database entries, it's not a hard requirement, nor is it done automatically for you.

These are just default endpoints created as part of the REST interface. `create` could send an email when you submit a form, or it could forward the call to some API. It's entirely up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the help. You answer was very enlightening.